# Does deleting a Trello account delete all boards you own?

Tags: trello

If I create a board or two on [Trello](http://trello.com/), add other users to the boards, but don't make them admin, then delete my account, do the boards disappear, as I'm the only admin?

Or, do the other users then have a board they can't delete? Or does someone get assigned the admin status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to delete your account, but you are the only admin on at least one board, it will not let you delete the account and instead will direct you to the boards on which you must change someone else to an admin.

Comment: That's a shame - was wondering if it was a way around the lack of deletion for boards!

Comment: @IainHallam It will, however, delete boards if you are the only member.

Comment: Excellent! I shall have to try that with a new board some time.